# Find non-overlapping segments between collinear lines

Tags: geometry

Is there a mathematical way (formula) to find the non-overlapping points given 2 collinear lines. Say

```
AB, A (0, 0) and B (15, 0) form a line segment and
CD, C(2,0) and D(6, 0) is another line segment
```

It's easy enough to find the overlapping points using some form of min/max. How do you find non-overlapping points? I can write bunch of if conditions to achieve it, but I wonder if there's a mathematical way to get the answer (just like finding overlapping points). In this example I'd expect it to return 2 line segments that're not overlapping,

```
line between (0, 0) and (1, 0) and
line between (7, 0) and (15, 0)
```

Comment: What is your _definition_ of a _mathematical_ method?

Comment: I was wondering if there's an algorithm similar to working out overlapping line segment's start/end (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15812696/327702) - I said mathematical, but all I mean is some proven property that I could use to work out the line segments that don't overlap

Comment: what input does the algorithm take?

Comment: Just points for line segment (0, 0) (15, 0) we're testing with and list of other line segments like [ ( (2,0), (5, 0) ), ( (-2, 0), (4, 0)) ] etc and I need multiple line segments that doesn't overlap with this list. There'll be no overlaps between these points itself in the list.

Comment: @DS did what I said make sense?

Comment: For given 2 points, the equation of the _line_ (which is infinite in length) can be represented as $y = mx+c$, where $m$ is the slope and $c$ is the y-intercept. No, you can write the 2 points in the form of $(p,f(p))$. If $f(x)$ is not equal for the $2$ lines, they are not overlapping. If it is equal, you can use min-max on $p$ to check if they are overlapping and how much part is overlapping.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything I could do after that to find the segments that are not overlapping. I pretty much go find overlapping points and then run through some if blocks to find the non overlapping segments. You may get 2 line segments that don't overlap out of testing with one line segment. I can draw it out to explain better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to understand your question. Suppose you have found that line *segments* $AB$ and $CD$ *have* some overlapping line segment. The co-ordinates of $A,B,C,D$ are $(a,f(a)), \ (b,f(b)), \ (c,f(c)), \ (d,f(d))$. The *union* of the line segments is the line segment joining $(s,f(s))$ and $(g,f(g))$, where $s = \min(a,b,c,d)$ and $g = \max(a,b,c,d)$. The segment joining the other two points will be the **overlapping** part.

Clearly, the overlapping part is a *single* line segment. **The non-overlapping part** is the union minus the overlapping part. So, the non overlapping part will be the segment joining $(s,f(s))$ and $(m,f(m))$ and the segement joining $(n,f(n))$ and $(g,f(g))$ where $m$ and $n$ are abscissae of the other two points and $m<n$.

---

In your example $a = 0$, $b = 15$, $c = 2$ and $d = 6$. So, $s = a = 0$ and $g = b = 15$. Hence, $m = c = 2$ and $n = d = 6$. So, the non-overlapping parts will be 2 line segments:

- The segment joining $(s,f(s)) = (0,0)$ and $(m,f(m)) = (2,0)$.
- The segment joining $(n,f(n)) = (6,0)$ and $(g,f(g)) = (15,0)$.

Note that one of the segments can be of zero length iff $AB$ and $CD$ share an endpoint are coincident. Both segments are of zero length iff $AB = CD$.

Comment: Thanks - I think I generally follow your reasoning (union minus overlapping), but I'm not sure about f(a) notation, in (a, f(a)) for example what is f(a)? Is that a function of a? In my example since it's a collinear line and assuming all of them line on same vertical axis, y=0, then f(a) = 0?

Comment: yes., that's right. But often, the line need not be vertical, it can be oblique. Consider the line, $y = x$, where $f(a) = a$.